# Click on elements using Bounds in UIAutomator?

Tags: android, appium, android-uiautomator

I am using `appium_lib` gem to automate my android tests. I have an element, which doesn't have a `text` , `content-desc` , `resource-id` to identify. I have tried several methods to have it identified like

```
find_element(class: "android.widget.Imageview").click   #But the problem is, an other element also has the same class"
```

I tried using xpath to click this

```
find_element(xpath: "//android.widget.LinearLayout[@index='1']/android.widget.ImageView[@index='0']").click
```

Still it wouldn't click on the element.

The bounds that I find in the UI automator for this element is `[43,676][265,972]`

How do I use this info to click on that element.

Answer (score 0):

Bounds is not a good approach, as its values would change on different devices and different screen sizes. Xpath option would be the right approach.

But if you still want try Bounds, you can write a custom function where you can use `element.getLocation()` method, which returns the top-left corner of the object. You would then need to compare this value with the Bounds data.

Comment: Thanks! I still couldn't be successful with the bounds, but I was luckily able to follow the hierarchy structure and locate the element.